# Count Sort in C - problem with output and count_array

Tags: c, counting-sort

I am trying to implement a count sort algorithm in C for uni. The task was pretty easy because we were given pseudocode to translate into c-code. But somehow my `count_array` and `output_array` go crazy. But i don't see where i am writing in indices i am not supposed to or where there is a memory fault.

Edit: The console gives out the following

```
Unsortiertes Array:(print input_array) 90 38 42 34 8 0 77 1 84 5 25 72 44 42 90 63 23

(print count_array) -363607072 32766 233318081 1 1 0 0 0 -363606696 32766 -363606200 32766 1805418521 32767 13 0 0

Sortiertes Array: print output_array) 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

What am i doing wrong? i think it is the `output_array[k] = j;` in `count_sort_write_output_array` but when i look up other counting sort algos on the internet thats how its supposed to be written, or not?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "arrayio.h"

int MAX_LAENGE = 1000;
int MAX_VALUE = 100;
int j, i, k;


void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[]) {
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        count_array[input_array[j]] = count_array[input_array[j]] + 1;
    }
}

void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int len, int count_array[]) {
    k = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < count_array[j]; i++) {
            output_array[k] = j;
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Aufruf: %s <Dateiname>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s zahlen.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];

    int input_array[MAX_LAENGE];
    int len = read_array_from_file(input_array, MAX_LAENGE, filename);

    printf("Unsortiertes Array:");
    print_array(input_array, len);

     int count_array[MAX_LAENGE];
     // print_array(count_array, len);
     int output_array[MAX_LAENGE];
     count_sort_calculate_counts(input_array, len, count_array);
     count_sort_write_output_array(output_array, len, count_array);

    printf("Sortiertes Array:");

    print_array(output_array, len);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should initialize your whole count_array to zeros

Comment: by the way, making `i`, `j`, and `k` as global variables is generally a bad idea as a way to define iterating variables.  Some day in the furure you will have one subroutine call another that both use them, and the inner one will corrupt the outer one

Comment: Showing `print_array()` would help!